# Java - Thread - Address already in use (net bind)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a 2 button using Swing API to handle a Socket server thread.
The problem is, when I start a new Socket Server is success.

```
  Java Thread ID:19
```

But when I stop, and start again : its said

```
Java Thread ID:20 
Exception server handler: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

Here is the source code. Any help it so appreciated.

```
private Thread worker;
private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private boolean isRunning() {
  return running.get();
}

private void interrupt() {
  running.set(false);
  worker.interrupt();
}

// Function start a thread server socket
private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
  // Validation
  if (textFieldDirectory.getText() != null && !textFieldDirectory.getText().isEmpty()) {

    worker = new Thread(new ServerHandler());
    worker.start();

    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);

  
  } else {
    textAreaLog.append(this.createLog("Please", "Failed"));
    
  }
}


// Function stop those thread
private void btnStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   interrupt();
        
   btnStart.setEnabled(true);
   btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        
}    


public class ServerHandler implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {
     try {
        running.set(true);

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(59090);
        while (isRunning()) {
            
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            // create each thread for client
            Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            listener.start();
            textAreaLog.append("\n" + "Thread Listering: " + listener.getName() + "\n");
        }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
        textAreaLog.append("Exception server handler: " + ex.getMessage());
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You only need to create the `ServerSocket` once. But if you want to re-create it every time the user clicks on the relevant `JButton`, then you need to close it first, before you re-create it.

Comment: The problem is, Java swing (JButton here is locked the Thread). So, I need another thread for handle Socket Server.

Comment: _I need another thread for handle Socket Server_ You are creating another thread in method `btnStartActionPerformed`. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Then I can copy your code and run it on my computer and reproduce your problem.